# fontspec WordSpace Unclear

Tags: fontspec, letterspacing

Page 27 of the fontspec package reads:

> The space in between words in a paragraph will be chosen automatically, and generally
> will not need to be adjusted. For those times when the precise details are important,
> the WordSpace feature is provided, which takes either a single scaling factor to scale the default
> value, or a triplet of comma-separated values to scale the nominal value, the stretch,
> and the shrink of the interword space by, respectively. (WordSpace={x} is the same as
> WordSpace={x,x,x}.)

It's unclear what the parameters of the WordSpace with triple arguments mean. Let's say that I want to use interword spacing that can stretch or shrink by up to 5% (I know this is bad typography). What WordSpace={x,x,x} should I use?
My guess is WordSpace={1,1.05,0.95}, but again, the package instructions aren't clear.

Comment: You would need a lower level setting, the fontspec `WordSpace` just lets you scale the font specified stretch so you can not directly specify stretch as a percentage of the unstretched value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three values are factors by which the font parameters are multiplied.

You can exploit the fact that when the font is being defined, `\font` will refer to it. The standard interword space is `\fontdimen2\font`, the stretchability is `\fontdimen3\font` and the shrinkability is `\fontdimen4\font`.

Now it's a matter of dividing the interword space by the stretchability and shrinkability, multiplying these quotients by the factors you wish, in your case 0.05 for both.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  WordSpace={
    1,
    \fpeval{0.05*(\the\fontdimen2\font)/(\the\fontdimen3\font)},
    \fpeval{0.05*(\the\fontdimen2\font)/(\the\fontdimen4\font)}
  },
]

\begin{document}

Standard space: \the\fontdimen2\font

Stretchability: \the\fontdimen3\font

Shrinkability: \the\fontdimen4\font

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the answer has been reworked, you can read the original idea in the edit history.